# Python Create column based on existing column with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe with this format :

[image]

Ihave created an empty column USD Amount and i want to fill it with the currnecy converted in USD. i used the below code :

```
for cur in df1['CurrencyCode']:
    if cur=='RMB':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/6.39
    elif cur=='THB':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/33.26
    elif cur=='INR':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/75.01
    elif cur=='KRW':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/1,171.56
    elif cur=='VND':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/22,759.00
    elif cur=='IDR':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/14,188.86
    elif cur=='MYR':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/4.15
    elif cur=='USD':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/1
    elif cur=='EUR':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/0.86
    elif cur=='TUS':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/1
    elif cur=='GBP':
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/33.26
    else:
        df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']
```

but i get:

```
      7         df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/75.01
      8     elif cur=='KRW':
----> 9         df1['USD Amount']=df1['Amount']/1,171.56
     10     elif cur=='VND':
     11         df1['USD Amount']=round(df1['Amount']/22,759.00,2)
```

**ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (9892)**

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I think these are comma issues. I think in line 9 the value should be 1171.56 and in line 11 it should be 22759 and line 13 should be 14188.86.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this answer if this solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much , that seemed to be the problem. Thank you again.

Comment: @GeorgePapadopoulos Anytime! Please accept my answer (this is good practice on SO if your problem was resolved).

Comment: Although i just found out that the if elif statements i used do not actually work because they convert only using the first currency all the amounts.It doesnt use the if statements for all the other currencies. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the commas in the conversion rates and created a function to apply to the dataframe

```
dict=[{'Username':'GEO','CurrencyCode':'EUR','Amount':1000},
  {'Username':'BUCK17','CurrencyCode':'GBP','Amount':1000},
  {'Username':'DRAC77','CurrencyCode':'LBP','Amount':1000}]

df=pd.DataFrame(dict)

def ConvertCurrency(row):
    ret_val=0.0
    if row['CurrencyCode']=='RMB':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/6.39
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='THB':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/33.26
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='INR':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/75.01
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='KRW':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/1171.56
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='VND':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/22759.00
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='IDR':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/14188.86
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='MYR':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/4.15
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='USD':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/1
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='EUR':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/0.86
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='TUS':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/1
    elif row['CurrencyCode']=='GBP':
        ret_val=row['Amount']/33.26
    else:
       ret_val=row['Amount']
    
    return ret_val

df['USD Amount']=df.apply(ConvertCurrency,axis=1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Username CurrencyCode  Amount   USD Amount
0      GEO          EUR    1000  1162.790698
1   BUCK17          GBP    1000    30.066146
2   DRAC77          LBP    1000  1000.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my problem. Thank you again.